# Failure when attempting to connect R to Oracle database via DBI using 19C client on Linux

Tags: r, linux, oracle, odbc

Oracle 19C DB hosted on Azure Linux VM
Existing R installation on Linux server with Oracle 12 client installed can connect to new DB
New R installation on Azure Linux VM with Oracle 19 client installed cannot connect to new DB

Existing RHEL with Oracle 12 client:

```
connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                               Driver = "libsqora.so.12.1",
                               DBQ    = "dbhostname:1521/sid",
                               UID    = "username",
                               PWD    = "password")
```

**connects to database**

New Azure RHEL VM with Oracle 19 client:

```
connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                               Driver = "libsqora.so.19.1",
                               DBQ    = "dbhostname:1521/sid",
                               UID    = "username",
                               PWD    = "password")
```

**Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 632 ▒: 523 630**

**Supplemental Information from new VM:**

odbcListDrivers is not returning the drivers list

```
> odbcListDrivers()
[1] name      attribute value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

ODBCSYSINI=~/odbc
odbc.ini and ~/odbc/.odbc.ini are empty same as existing VM

odbcinst.ini and ~/odbc/.odbcinst.ini contain the following on new VM (more entries than on old VM):

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the freetds-libs package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[FreeTDS]
Description     = Free Sybase & MS SQL Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libtdsS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
Port            = 1433


# Driver from the mariadb-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MariaDB]
Description     = ODBC for MariaDB
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

Additionally, ~/odbc/.odbcinst.ini contains

```
[Oracle19c]
Description = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 19c
Driver = /opt/app/oraclnt/oracle/product/191100cl/lib/libsqora.so.19.1
FileUsage = 1
```

I've also attempted to test connection with RODBC to no avail.

Can connect to the Oracle DB via sqlplus on this VM.

Have tried reinstalling odbc_1.3.2.tar.gz package.

UPDATE:

I failed to mention that I am not an R developer. Our solution was built by a third party company under contract last year. I am primarily a database developer with some frontend experience in c# & .Net. Contracting development is not an option currently.

Following the suggestion to try ROracle, here are the results:

- Trying to install ROracle 1.3-2 made me realize that the new Linux VM was running R 4.1.1 - where the old code was running 3.6.0
- I had 4.1.1. removed and replaced with 3.6.0
- The original problem outlined above still persisted
- ROracle 1.3-2 from the link below would not install properly, but version 1.3-1 from CRAN did install
- I was manually able to get a connection to the new Oracle 19 DB and run queries
- I then managed to update config.R & connections.R to create a connection in the code for the various functions to use
- I also updated the Description file to include the dependency for ROracle

While the underlying modules could now connect to the database, it has created new issues

- The code seems to be able to read and process the data, but crashes when trying to write saying the table isn't there, even though it is
- Deeper issues with modules:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `module_name`. ✖ `false` must be a list, not a double vector.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for resolving the original issue???

Comment: I've had problems with `DBI::dbConnect()` before, but it was with MS SQL. Your problem might be the same, i don't know. The problem is that the function silently ignores your arguments if they are not the exact correct capitalization and/or name such as 'pwd' or 'password' or 'uid' vs 'UID'. I found some working examples of the `dbConnect` being used with MS SQL and used exactly the same arguement names as in the example. That worked.

Comment: Use ROracle from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html (note the CRAN package is slightly older - their tooling hasn't let us upload the new one)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Added updates after trying ROracle